# Overlay two plots from different dataframes in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to overlay two ggplots from different data sources. I don't think a `left_join` will work because the dataframes are of two different lengths and would potential change the underlying plots.[Maybe?]

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
player_df <- tibble(name = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each = 10, times = 1),
                    pos = rep(c("DEF","DEF","MID","MID"), each = 10, times = 1),
                    load = c(rnorm(10, mean = 200, sd = 100),
                             rnorm(10, mean = 300, sd = 50),
                             rnorm(10, mean = 400, sd = 100),
                             rnorm(10, mean = 500, sd = 50)))

p1 <- player_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = load, y = name)) +
  geom_point()


pos_df <- tibble(pos = rep(c("DEF","MID"), each = 30, times = 1),
                 load = (c(rnorm(30, mean = 250, sd = 100),
                           rnorm(30, mean = 350, sd = 100))))

p2 <- pos_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = load, y = pos)) +
  geom_boxplot()

p1
p2

# add p2 to every p1 player plot by pos
```

I would like `p1` to have the corresponding `p2` - by `pos` - appear behind it. So... add the matching `p2` boxplot to each `p1` scatterplot.

`p1`:
[image: plot of players]

`p2`:
[image: boxplot of position]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dug into ggplot a bit and re-engineered a boxplot bit by bit.

```
# manually calculate stats that are used in boxplots
pos_df_summary <- pos_df %>%
  group_by(pos, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
  summarise(min = fivenum(load)[1],
            Q1 = fivenum(load)[2],
            median = fivenum(load)[3],
            Q3 = fivenum(load)[4],
            max = fivenum(load)[5]
            )
# add the boxplot data to each player
joined_df <- player_df %>% 
  left_join(., pos_df_summary, by = "pos") %>% 
  distinct(name, .keep_all = TRUE)

# plot
ggplot(data = NULL, aes(group = name)) +
  # create the line from min to max
  geom_segment(data = joined_df, aes(y = name, yend = name, x=min, xend=max), color="black") +
  #create the box with median line
  geom_crossbar(data = joined_df, 
                aes(y = name, xmin = Q1, xmax = Q3, x = median, fill = "NA"),
                color = "black",
                fatten = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "white") +
  # add the points from the player_df
  geom_point(data = player_df, 
             aes(x = load, y = name, group=name),
             color = "red",
             show.legend=FALSE) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: final plot combining to dataframes]

There may be some extraneous code in here as I cobbled it from some other resources. Specifically, I'm not sure what the `aes(group = name)` in the `ggplot()` call does exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really advisable to attempt to superimpose two plots on each other. A ggplot is made of layers already, so usually it's just a case of superimposing one `geom` on another. This can be difficult if (as in your case) one of the axes has different labels. However, with a little work it is possible to wrangle your data so that it all sits on a single plot. In your case, you could do something like:

```r
levs <- c("A", "DEF", "B", "C", "MID", "D")

ggplot(within(pos_df, pos <- factor(pos, levs)), aes(x = load, y = pos)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 2.3) +
  geom_point(data = within(player_df, pos <- factor(name, levs))) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = c("A", "DEF", "B", " ", "C", "MID", "D"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Allan! A lot cleaner than mine but I'm worried it will take a bit of work to write `levs` and `scale_y_discrete()` for a larger data set. I haven't seen `within()` being used before so thanks for adding that to my bag of tricks!